# How can I change the Value name for an incorrect Visual Studio 2012 Registry key: {00A9524F-427F-46EE-8A20-615C25ECBE6F}?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012, registry

Sending out an SOS

I made a discovery while trying to understand my last VS 2012 installation error. These two errors appear at the bottom of the ActivityLog when I open VS 2012:

**34 ERROR CreateInstance failed for package [SqlStudio Profile Package] {00A9524F-427F-46EE-8A20-615C25ECBE6F} 80070002 VisualStudio 2013/03/14 13:02:07.904**

**35 ERROR End package load [SqlStudio Profile Package] {00A9524F-427F-46EE-8A20-615C25ECBE6F} 80004005 - E_FAIL VisualStudio 2013/03/14 13:02:07.928**

This morning, I found a post from bizcad on 6/4/2012 at 10:14 AM on Microsoft Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746372/sqlstudio-editor-package-did-not-load-correctly

I quote:

*"Tracking down where the missing file was I searched the registry for **{00A9524F-427F-46EE-8A20-615C25ECBE6F}.** The CodeBase entry showed C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLEditor\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlEditor.dll. Note the two backslashes after 10.0. Remove 1 of the backslashes"*

I performed the same registry search on the same key and discovered that the registry Value name I have for that key under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\BindingPaths** reads this way:

**\pc-ts\c\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB**

Note the missing backslash between 11.0 and Common7.

I think that the incorrect path is causing the VS error. I also note that this Value name has no Value data.

**Question 1:** How can I safely add the missing backslash to this seemingly incorrect Value name for this Visual Studio 2012 Registry key?

**Question 2:** Should Value data have content?

Thanks for your help,

Arnold

Comment: It is fine on my machine, no double or missing slash.  The value is supposed to be empty.  The "pc-ts" prefix is weird, is this running on some kind of terminal service.  Probably has something to do with it.  Just edit the value name.

Comment: @Hans. The prefix is my machine on the corporate network. Thanks for the confirmation re the expectation of content in Value data.

Comment: @Hans. I'd like to Accept your answer, but I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct the key in regedit.
First copy the (corrected) directory location, (paste in notepad, correct it and copy it to clip board.

In regedit: 
- right click the parent key  {00A9524F-427F-46EE-8A20-615C25ECBE6F} 
- click new -> string value

paste in the corrected directory location, and you'll see the old value with the error next to the new... then go ahead and delete the old one with the typo.

hopefully this works.